# UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `Bucket_Name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `ap-south-1' region

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD8zx.png)

I am getting this error while doing S3-multipart Upload for files greater than 1 GB even though I have stable Internet Connectivity.
So here is my Entire Code for S3-Multipart Upload.

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    region: region,
    correctClockSkew: true,
    httpOptions: {
        timeout: 900000      
    }
})

const startTime = new Date();
let partNum = 0;
const partSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
const maxUploadTries = 3;
const multipartMap = {
    Parts: []
}

async function s3MultipartUpload(s3Params) {
    try {
        console.log('##### Entered into s3VideoUpload #####');
        console.log('S3VideoUpload Params : ', s3Params);
        console.log('Start Time : ', startTime);
        console.log('Buffer Length : ', s3Params.Body.length);
        global.numPartsLeft = Math.ceil(s3Params.Body.length / partSize);
        const multiPartParams = {
            Bucket: s3Params.Bucket,
            Key: s3Params.Key,
            ContentType: s3Params.contentType
        }
        console.log('PartNum : ', partNum, 'partSize : ', partSize, 'numPartsLeft : ', numPartsLeft);
        console.log('multiPartParams : ', multiPartParams);
        console.log('creating Multipart upload for :', s3Params.Key);
        s3.createMultipartUpload(multiPartParams, function (mpErr, multipart) {
            if (mpErr) {
                throw new Error(mpErr);
            }
            console.log('Got Upload ID : ', multipart.UploadId);

            for (let start = 0; start < s3Params.Body.length; start += partSize) {
                console.log('For Loop numPartsLeft : ', numPartsLeft);
                partNum++;
                const end = Math.min(start + partSize, s3Params.Body.length);
                const partParams = {
                    Body: s3Params.Body.slice(start, end),
                    Bucket: multiPartParams.Bucket,
                    Key: multiPartParams.Key,
                    PartNumber: String(partNum),
                    UploadId: multipart.UploadId,
                };
                console.log('Uploading Part : ##', partParams.PartNumber, ' # Start : ', start);
                uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams)
                console.log("numPartsLeft For Loop : ", numPartsLeft);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}

async function uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams, tryNum) {
    try {
        console.log('####Entered into uploadPart####');
        var tryNum = tryNum || 1;     
        console.log('tryNum >>>>', tryNum);
        s3.uploadPart(partParams, function (multiErr, mData) {
            console.log('#### Started ####');
            if (multiErr) {
                console.log('Upload part error:', multiErr);
                if (tryNum < maxUploadTries) {
                    console.log('Retrying upload of part: #', partParams.PartNumber);
                    uploadPart(s3, multipart, partParams, tryNum + 1);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Failed uploading part: #', partParams.PartNumber);
                    
                }
              return;    
            }

            multipartMap.Parts[this.request.params.PartNumber - 1] = {
                ETag: mData.ETag,
                PartNumber: Number(this.request.params.PartNumber),
            };

            console.log('Completed Part :', this.request.params.PartNumber);
            console.log('mData : ', mData);

            console.log('NumPartLeft : ', numPartsLeft);
            if (--numPartsLeft > 0) return;   // complete only when all parts uploaded

            var doneParams = {
                Bucket: partParams.Bucket,
                Key: partParams.Key,
                MultipartUpload: multipartMap,
                UploadId: multipart.UploadId
            };

            console.log('Completing Upload ....');
            completeMultipartUpload(s3, doneParams);
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}

async function completeMultipartUpload(s3, doneParams) {
    try {
        s3.completeMultipartUpload(doneParams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
            else {
                const delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
                console.log('Completed Upload In : ', delta, 'seconds');
                console.log('Final Upload Data  : ', data);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

I have stable Internet Connectivity and it does not retry to upload the chunk that failed in 1st attempt . The execution gets stuck after the error.

[Execution stuck at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv9SI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to resolve your issue with this simple test code, and it is working fine with the 785.3 MB file. Hope it might help you to resolve your issue while you uploading large file. I know it pretty basic but you might enhance code by your own way.

Earlier I have suggested that you should use file streaming to read the file in-stream and deploy it in chunks.

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const fs = require("fs");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
  region: region,
  correctClockSkew: true,
  httpOptions: {
    timeout: 900000,
  },
});

/**
 * @description read file
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function readFile() {
  const fileName = "dump.txt";
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
  return {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: folderName,
    Body: readStream,
  };
}


/**
 * @description Uplaod allows to buffers, blob or stream using 
 *              configuration amount of concurrency to upload the file.
 * @param {Object} params 
 * @param {Object} options 
 * @returns 
 */
async function doUpload(params, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const s3 = new aws.S3({ httpOptions: { timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 } });
    s3.upload(params, options)
      .on("httpUploadProgress", function (event) {
        const progressPercent = ((event.loaded * 100) / event.total).toFixed();
        console.log(`${progressPercent}% file is uploaded`);
      })
      .send(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
  });
}

/**
 * @description initialize uploading
 */
async function init() {
  const params = readFile();
  // Chunk of 5 kb with concurrency 10 chunks is queued.
  const options = { partSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 10 };
  const s3 = new aws.S3({ httpOptions: { timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 } });
  await doUpload(params, options)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("File has uploaded succesfully");
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error occured while uploading");
      console.error(err);
    });
}

init();
```

Hope this might put some light on your issue and code.

Comment: Thank you @DipakC but this could not solve my problem . I am still getting an error  - UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `bucket_Name.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `ap-south-1' region.

Comment: @SwetaRajbhar if this works with the 800Mb file smoothly then definitely, the issue with your bucket configuration. You must review yours was bucket configuration, else this code is working perfectly on my aws server without any issue.